# RSS Feed for magento Stackexchange

Tags: feature-request, rss

Am I blind? Or is there no feed for all questions? If there is no, how do we get one? :-)

How much text, do I need to write to "meet our quality standards"?
Answer: this was enough now. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/feeds/ ?

Comment: Is there a link somewhere I didn't see?